# Uniqueness of passing to the quotient space mapping

Tags: general-topology, continuity, quotient-spaces

From Intro to Topological Manifolds by Lee:

> [image]

Since we are constructing this map, we know it exists.

However, I having trouble elaborating showing the map is well-defined and unique.

**How can this argument be spelled out more?**

Comment: Well-defined here means the choice of $x$ didn't matter (another $x_1$ that maps to $y$ wouldn't change your map). Uniqueness means any other map fitting into that diagram has to be the same at every point. Can you show both of these are true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $y \in Y$ then we want to define $\tilde{f}$ such that $\tilde{f} \circ q = f$, so the only way we can define $\tilde{f}(y)$ is to take some $x$ with $q(x) = y$ ($q$ must be surjective, so such $x$ exist) and define $\tilde{f}(y) = f(x)$. For this $x$ we then automatically have $$(\tilde{f} \circ q)(x) = \tilde{f}(q(x)) = \tilde{f}(y) = f(x)$$ This map $\tilde{f}$ is well-defined because whatever $x$ or $x'$ we choose with $q(x) = y$ or $q(x') = y$, we always have $x \in q^{-1}[\{y\}]$ and $x' \in q^{-1}[\{y\}]$, so $x, x'$ are both in the $q$-fibre of $y$.

And the condition of constance on $q$-fibres means that $f$ assumed only one value on this fibre $q^{-1}[\{y\}]$ or, as stated in the theorem:

$$\forall x,x' \in X: q(x) = q(x') \to f(x) = f(x')$$

which states exactly the condition that we can choose any point of $x \in X$ to define $\tilde{f}(y)$ as long as $q(x) = y$. This covers well-definedness.

The unicity was already clear above: the condition that $\tilde{f} \circ q = f$ leaves us no choice: suppose $f': Y \to Z$ were another function satisfying that condition, then $f'(y) = f'(q(x))$ for some $x \in X$ by surjectivity, and so this should equal $f(x)$ by the commutativity condition, just like $\tilde{f}(y)$ for that $x$. So the map is clearly unique.